# IIS applications appear in appcmd but not in IIS manager tree view

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, appcmd

I have some web servers running Windows Server 2008 Std with IIS 7.

I've noticed a strange thing about the configuration. I see some Apps and Virtual Directories in appcmd that don't show up in the tree view in IIS manager. Note, this is not a confusion caused by the fact that applications show up in the vdir list in appcmd!

For example, from appcmd list app:-

```
APP "BaseMetals/_testing_/Cache" (applicationPool:MyDeskBMCache)
APP "BaseMetals/_testing_/CCache" (applicationPool:ContentCache)
APP "BaseMetals/_testing_/scoop" (applicationPool:ScoopPublic4)
```

And from appcmd list vdir:-

```
VDIR "BaseMetals/_testing_/Cache/" (physicalPath:D:\fm_websites\BM\MyDesk\Cache)
VDIR "BaseMetals/_testing_/CCache/" (physicalPath:D:\fm_websites\FMContentCache_MYDESK)
VDIR "BaseMetals/_testing_/scoop/" (physicalPath:D:\fm_websites\Scoop\Scoop Public)
```

If I select the site "BaseMetals" in IIS Manager and click "View Applications", I can see these applications in the list there. They also show up if I select the relevant Application Pool and click "View Applications" there. However, they definitely do not appear in the tree on the left-hand side.

Why do these applications not show up? Is something broken about their configuration? How can I use appcmd or powershell to extract a list of broken application/vdir entries in order to clean them out?

Comment: I may have partially answered my own question. The app BaseMetals has a physical path of D:\fm_websites\BM\MyDesk. The three apps above have virtual paths Basemetals/_testing_/... but there is no VDIR or app that maps to Basemetals/_testing_ itself, and no D:\fm_websites\BM\MyDesk\_testing_ directory exists in the filesystem. If I create a directory there, the apps appear when I refresh the tree.

This does still leave open the question of how to scan the configuration for this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the comment above, here's a tool to scan for this problem. Not the most elegant piece of code ever, but possibly useful to someone.

https://bitbucket.org/fastmarkets/iis_lint